# Appending text from one variable onto another variable

Tags: bash, shell, append

I created have two variables

```
 LOC="Testing/"
 AVAILABLEDIR="Directory1/ Directory2/ Directory3/"
```

What I want done is to append "Directory1/" ONLY onto "Testing/" and then perform a function on the resulting value of "Testing/Directory1/".

I then want "Directory2/" ONLY to be appended onto Testing/, and the same function performed on it.

I then want "Directory3/" ONLY to be appended onto Testing/, and the same function performed on it.

The variables will change, and I want the contents of AVAILABLEDIR to always be appended onto LOC in this manner so that the same function can be performed on it, regardless the length of the list in AVAILABLEDIR

```
for a in $AVAILABLEDIR; do
  LOC=$(echo "$LOC" | sed s/$/$AVAILABLEDIR//g)
  myfunction
done
```

This my attempt, however all it does is append the characters "$AVAILABLEDIR" to the end of my variable LOC.

I don't really know how to do this, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need different variable names:

```
DIRBASE="Testing/"
AVAILABLEDIR="Directory1/ Directory2/ Directory3/"

for a in $AVAILABLEDIR; do
  LOC="$DIRBASE$a"
  myfunction
done
```

This is a bit cleaner, just in case a directory name contains a space:

```
DIRBASE="Testing/"
AVAILABLEDIR=(Directory1/ Directory2/ Directory3/)

for a in "${AVAILABLEDIR[@]}"; do
   LOC="$DIRBASE$a"
   myfunction
done
```